# Is sugar really the enemy?

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, muscle-gain, fat, sugar

I have been researching online a lot regarding the truth of sugar and there's so many mixed opinion. I was hoping for some objective opinion regarding the matter and hopefully backed with scientific knowledge.

For the last few months I have been tracking my macros-nutrients and performing adequate exercise thinking they would be enough for me to stay healthy and just live a healthy life in general. However, I wasn't taking the sugar intake into account. And since I was using myfitnesspal to track my food, and the daily goal for sugar was about 100g I wasn't worried about the limit because it is usually bellow that and sometimes a little above. Until I became aware that sugar more than 30g is detrimental to health and that it can contribute to fat gain. An explanation I found was that sugar is harder burn completely contrary to what I assumed fuel my workout well, given sugar is carbs. Now I don't know if the information I provided is legit or is it just pure BS. But I hope someone out here can clear the air about the "truth" of sugars.

Is it dangerous to consume a whole bunch of sugar as much as 100 g daily for someone who has an adequate diet and performs adequate training?

Answer (score 1):

I think the question needs further refinement. Is sugar the enemy of what? Health? Gains? Weight-loss?

Sugar alone won’t cause anyone to gain fat. A surplus of calories will cause people to gain fat. To that regard any macro including sugar would be detrimental to fat loss if it is consumed In a caloric load that is greater than your TDEE or maintenance calories.

There is science out there that calls sugar the anti-nutrient and with good reason. As we find out more about our bodies constantly being under a state of high insulin we know that it leads to metabolic syndrome and diabetes. These are reversed by limiting sugar intake so in that sense yes sugar is the enemy.

However, if you’re following a 95% quality caloric profile and you have some sugar but maintain your caloric deficit, it would not harm any fat loss or magically make you gain weight.

I would suggest generally staying away from sugar, limit intake thereby limiting cravings. There are a ton of sugar alternatives out there, find one you like. Fat loss is about finding alternatives to the caloric dense foods we love by replacing them with lower calorie substitutes.

Also MyFitnessPal is a great tool but we should be setting our own goals. The goals of 100g of sugar is generic and your goals will be different than the one size fits all approach the app defaults to.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I guess, in the end, I was kinda concerned about the overall health effects of sugar rather than in fat loss becuz the energy balance is essentially what's needed to be considered when it comes to weight gain/loss. So, to be healthy in general it is best recommended to limit sugar intake and to negate the harms of high insulin and blood sugar level etc. Do you think heavy resistance training and cardio say about 5 times a week enough to negate the effects of consuming around 70-100 g of sugar daily? If no...how much reduction of sugar would you suggest?

Comment: Consistently high insulin is the problem, insulin spikes are a natural part of the human body in response to carbohydrates and large amounts of protein. I think heavy resistance training is one part of an overall picture of general wellness and maintaining a wellness focused lifestyle. If you're getting 100g of sugar a day, find alternatives to reduce that amount. I usually consume less than 30g of sugar per day by switching to Lite syrups and sauces and low carb tortillas, keto bread, etc. There are great alternatives to cookies, breads, and other high carb foods.I hope this helps my friend!